# overriding LESS variable with divshot.com

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less, divshot

I'm playing around with the divshot.com UI creator.

It'sPretty slick.

I can't seem to override a LESS variable though.
I'm sure I'm just doing something stupid.

If I put something like this:

```
@navbarBackground: #f3a428;
```

In the CSS/LESS editor... shouldn't that work?
the divshot.com editor seems to be evaluating the code for compile... but it doesn't appear the changes are ever applied to the page. (I've waited) :)

I even tried putting the following javascript in the JS editor with no luck

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   less.modifyVars({
     '@navbarBackground': '#f3a428'
   });
</script>
```

I realize JS only applies on preview and export - but even there nothing changed.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now the LESS that is added in Divshot does not compile along with Bootstrap, rather we are using a static CSS version of Bootstrap. We know that theme customization is something that many users want and have some plans to implement things (as well as allow for better use of the LESS mixins) but aren't there just yet.